# Different result with SSE version

Tags: c++, optimization, sse

I'm trying to rewrite some code to make use of SSE. However, for some reason  my SSE version produces different results than the original, e.g. 209.1 instead of 1.47 etc..

Why? The entire function can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Gmbqg0qG).

```
struct vec_ps
{
    __m128 value;

    vec_ps(){}  
    vec_ps(float value)         : value(_mm_set1_ps(value)) {}
    vec_ps(__m128 value)        : value(value)              {}
    vec_ps(const vec_ps& other) : value(other.value)        {}

    vec_ps& operator=(const vec_ps& other)
    {
        value = other.value;
        return *this;
    }

    vec_ps& operator+=(const vec_ps& other)
    {
        value = _mm_add_ps(value, other.value);
        return *this;
    }

    vec_ps& operator-=(const vec_ps& other)
    {
        value = _mm_sub_ps(value, other.value);
        return *this;
    }

    vec_ps& operator*=(const vec_ps& other)
    {
        value = _mm_mul_ps(value, other.value);
        return *this;
    }

    vec_ps& operator/=(const vec_ps& other)
    {
        value = _mm_div_ps(value, other.value);
        return *this;
    }

    static vec_ps load(float* ptr)
    {
        return vec_ps(_mm_load_ps(ptr));
    }

    static void stream(float* ptr, const vec_ps& other)
    {
        _mm_stream_ps(ptr, other.value);
    }

    void stream(float* ptr)
    {
        _mm_stream_ps(ptr, value);
    }
};

vec_ps operator+(const vec_ps& lhs, const vec_ps& rhs)
{       
    return vec_ps(lhs) += rhs;
}

vec_ps operator-(const vec_ps& lhs, const vec_ps& rhs)
{       
    return vec_ps(lhs) -= rhs;
}

vec_ps operator*(const vec_ps& lhs, const vec_ps& rhs)
{       
    return vec_ps(lhs) *= rhs;
}

vec_ps operator/(const vec_ps& lhs, const vec_ps& rhs)
{       
    return vec_ps(lhs) /= rhs;
}

void foo(/*...*/)
{   
        std::vector<float, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<float>> ref_mu(w*h);
        std::vector<float, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<float>> cmp_mu(w*h);
        std::vector<float, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<float>> ref_sigma_sqd(w*h);
        std::vector<float, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<float>> cmp_sigma_sqd(w*h);
        std::vector<float, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<float>> sigma_both(w*h);
        int size    = w*h*sizeof(float);

        /*...*/

        float ssim_sum  = 0.0;
        float ssim_sum2 = 0.0;

        vec_ps ssim_sum_ps(0.0f);       

        for(int n = 0; n < size/16; ++n)
        {
            auto ref_mu_ps          = vec_ps::load(ref_mu.data()        + n*4);
            auto cmp_mu_ps          = vec_ps::load(cmp_mu.data()        + n*4);
            auto sigma_both_ps      = vec_ps::load(sigma_both.data()    + n*4);
            auto ref_sigma_sqd_ps   = vec_ps::load(ref_sigma_sqd.data() + n*4);
            auto cmp_sigma_sqd_ps   = vec_ps::load(cmp_sigma_sqd.data() + n*4);

            auto numerator   = (2.0f * ref_mu_ps * cmp_mu_ps + C1) * (2.0f * sigma_both_ps + C2);
            auto denominator = (ref_mu_ps*ref_mu_ps + cmp_mu_ps*cmp_mu_ps + C1) * (ref_sigma_sqd_ps + cmp_sigma_sqd_ps + C2);
            ssim_sum_ps += numerator / denominator; 
        }

        for(int n = 0; n < 4; ++n)
            ssim_sum2 += ssim_sum_ps.value.m128_f32[n];

        for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y)
        {
            int offset = y*w;
            for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x, ++offset) 
            {           
                float numerator   = (2.0f * ref_mu[offset] * cmp_mu[offset] + C1) * (2.0f * sigma_both[offset] + C2);
                float denominator = (ref_mu[offset]*ref_mu[offset] + cmp_mu[offset]*cmp_mu[offset] + C1) * (ref_sigma_sqd[offset] + cmp_sigma_sqd[offset] + C2);
                ssim_sum += numerator / denominator;                
            }
        }
        assert(ssim_sum2 == ssim_sum); // FAILS!
}
```

Comment: You can and should debug this yourself.  Run it in the debugger, or add printf calls to output intermediate results.  When you isolate the step that isn't working as expected, feel free to write a minimal test case and ask about it here.  But "here is a wall of code, figure out what's wrong" is not a good question.

Comment: @BenVoigt; Ofc, you are correct. However, I've alrdy done what you suggested before posting, without being able to figure it out.

Comment: So what line of code produces the "wrong" result?  Can you remove the TBB allocators, etc. and simplify things?

Comment: Is there any guarantee that `w * h` is divisible by four? If that isn't the case your last iteration in the SSE version will be based on random numbers. The use of `sizeof(float)` in one place and `16 instead of `4 * sizeof(float)` in another is somewhat confusing: why not leave off the size the of the `float`? Also, why doesn't the non-SSE version just run over the area instead of trying to follow the width and the height of the matrix?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Thx! That was the answer, I missed that w and h wasn't divisible by four. The non-SSE version was not written by me.

Comment: @Dietmar - you should make your comment an answer so that it can be marked as the answer.

Comment: @ronag - please do not delete your questions unless there is a compelling reason to do so, especially after someone has supplied you the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the comment above as it seems to be the answer to the question: Is there any guarantee that w * h is divisible by four? If that isn't the case your last iteration in the SSE version will be based on random numbers. The use of sizeof(float) in one place and 16 instead of 4 * sizeof(float)` in another is somewhat confusing: why not leave off the size the of the float? Also, why doesn't the non-SSE version just run over the area instead of trying to follow the width and the height of the matrix?